# How can I completely disable IPv6 on Debian (squeeze)?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I'm running Debian Squeeze (with a stock 2.6.32 kernel). I'd like to completely disable any kind of IPv6 traffic. Can I do this? There doesn't seem to be any relevant module loaded. Perhaps some setting in `/sys` or `/proc`?

I read [this](http://fak3r.com/2008/12/02/howto-disable-ipv6-networking-in-debian/), but my `/etc/modprobe.d/aliases` doesn't have a

```
alias net-pf-10 ipv6
```

line, it's commented-out already.

Comment: That's not IPv6 traffic. `SRC=192.168.2.100 DST=192.168.2.255`

Comment: @MichaelHampton: You're right. But the question is still generally relevant.

Comment: In that case, I will have to remind future readers that disabling IPv6 is generally a really bad idea, and should not be done except as a last resort, as it will cause you problems later when you _have_ to use IPv6.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's a simple process to re-enable it, assumng you remember. I disabled it as a quick fix (I've since changed the preference properly) on openSUSE a while ago, because it preferred IPv6 which would take a while to time out - giving me a not-so-nice several second delay on every request... But, yea, there's almost alwys a better way than flat out disabling it.

Comment: FYI: A working solution is at http://askubuntu.com/a/337736/164798

Comment: I realize this is old but I just inherited a WMWare Debian 6.0 install and the IPv6 is throwing issues all over the network. I've read on various VMWare sites that the solution is to disable IPv6 on VMs, which has already been done on the windows VMs. And as you may have guessed, this is an old VMWare install 5.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the answer in [Debian's Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6):

```
# echo net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 > /etc/sysctl.d/disableipv6.conf
```

But be aware that this disables IPv6 globally, so anything that needs it wont work properly.

Comment: Note that you need to restart your computer for this to be applied, but you probably already knew that.

Comment: To avoid a restart, you can load the configuration file with `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/disableipv6.conf` (I'm not too sure about this - I normally only use it on `/etc/sysctl.conf`) or directly set the value (non-persistent) with `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` or `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`

Comment: With Kernel 3.2.x this does not **completely** disable IPv6.  It only disables IPv6 Kernel autoconfiguration.  The IPv6 interface then is unconfigured and can induce major problems in IPv4-only-boxes.